# Async Await Without Task<T> method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

According to [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

// Add a using directive and a reference for System.Net.Http; 
using System.Net.Http;

namespace AsyncFirstExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Mark the event handler with async so you can use await in it. 
        private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call and await separately. 
            //Task<int> getLengthTask = AccessTheWebAsync(); 
            //// You can do independent work here. 
            //int contentLength = await getLengthTask; 

            int contentLength = await AccessTheWebAsync();

            resultsTextBox.Text +=
            String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength);
        }


        // Three things to note in the signature: 
        //  - The method has an async modifier.  
        //  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)
        //    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer. 
        //  - The method name ends in "Async."
        async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
        { 
            // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
            // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
            Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

            // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
                DoIndependentWork();

            // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync. 
            //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete. 
            //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync. 
            //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.  
            //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask. 
            string urlContents = await getStringTask;

            // The return statement specifies an integer result. 
            // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value. 
            return urlContents.Length;
        }


        void DoIndependentWork()
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "Working . . . . . . .\r\n";
        }
    }
}

// Sample Output: 

// Working . . . . . . . 

// Length of the downloaded string: 41564.
```

How replace the async web request call:

`Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");` with my own code block (that will contain a simple `for` loop)? Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

// Add a using directive and a reference for System.Net.Http; 
using System.Net.Http;

namespace AsyncFirstExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Mark the event handler with async so you can use await in it. 
        private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call and await separately. 
            //Task<int> getLengthTask = AccessTheWebAsync(); 
            //// You can do independent work here. 
            //int contentLength = await getLengthTask; 

            int contentLength = await AccessTheWebAsync();

            resultsTextBox.Text +=
            String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength);
        }


        // Three things to note in the signature: 
        //  - The method has an async modifier.  
        //  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)
        //    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer. 
        //  - The method name ends in "Async."
        async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
        { 
            // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
            // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
            Task<string> getStringTask = GetMyString(); // here

            // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
                DoIndependentWork();

            // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync. 
            //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete. 
            //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync. 
            //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.  
            //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask. 
            string urlContents = await getStringTask;

            // The return statement specifies an integer result. 
            // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value. 
            return urlContents.Length;
        }


        void DoIndependentWork()
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "Working . . . . . . .\r\n";
        }
    }
}

    private Task<string> GetMyString()
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            // compute str using simple c# code
        }
        // How to return str now?
    }
```

Comment: Well is `GetMyString` actually asynchronous in any useful way? If it's not, it's not going to work well when you use it with code which is *expecting* appropriate asynchronous code (i.e. it returns pretty much immediately, and the task will complete later).

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: No, `GetMyString` is not asynchronous. But I still want to make the call asynchronous

Comment: @yazanpro, do you mean that you want it to run in another thread? That's *not* the same as being asynchronous...

Comment: Yes, I seem to want it to run in another thread. I must be confusing the two concept!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to return str now

Like this:

```
private async Task<string> GetMyString()
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        // compute str using simple c# code
    }
    return str;
}
```

However, it doesn't really make sense, because the implementation of `GetMyString` isn't asynchronous; you never use `await` in it, and the compiler will warn you about it.

If you just want to run GetMyString in a separate thread, make it synchronous and run it with `Task.Run`:

```
private string GetMyString()
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        // compute str using simple c# code
    }
    return str;
}
```

...

```
Task<string> getStringTask = Task.Run(() => GetMyString());
```

Comment: Using a separate thread is exactly what I need. However, in order to make the answer complete, referring to "because the implementation of GetMyString isn't asynchronous", can you please elaborate how to implement `GetMyString` in an asynchronous way?
Also, please indicate how to prevent the compiler error caused by `return str;`

Comment: @yazanpro No, it's the idea of your implementation that isn't asynchronous. For example, if you're actually receiving data from a web server, that's an asynchronous I/O operation, and doesn't use up any threads. You're doing CPU work, so there's no opportunity to use asynchronous I/O, just parallelism (at best). The two are very different concepts, and the way `Task` and `Task<T>` are defined makes this rather confusing.

Comment: @yazanpro So the task returned by `Task.Run` is basically asynchronous I/O to the CPU worker thread it just created - but the actual work you're doing is still CPU work, not asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Implementing a method with the async keyword without using await raises a compiler warning. You could remove the async keyword and use "return Task.FromResult(str)" instead.